# Great performance penalty with Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join

I am having a "Listing" type table containing Id-Value pairs.
[image: Software Genius Inc.]

When I am executing normal query with a table without having join it takes only 2 secs to execute the query and generates more than 1900 records.
[image: Software Genius Inc.]
[image: Software Genius Inc.]

Now if i am applying an inner join with a single table, i have to pay performance penalty.
[image: Software Genius Inc.]
[image: Software Genius Inc.]

Can someone help me to get better way of joining.

Thanks for sharing your time and wisdom.

Comment: Your case is not different than the existing 1000 questions about performance optimization with SQL Server. Learn in general about SQL Server index tuning.

Comment: In the future, please post this as text, not pictures (this makes it easier to grab information for our own testing, and makes them easier to read, among other things).  Usually slowdowns in joins are due to not having a usable index, but I find that unlikely with the given tables.  Personally, I suspect that your statistics are likely out-of-date/not good.  Actually, I find the duration of the _first_ query suspicious - sorting 1900 rows is trivial for a computer.  For a starting set this size, optimizers generally grab **all** the rows.